# How to pass Header JWT Token with Axios & React?

Tags: reactjs, express, jwt

I make web application with React, Express, MongoDB.

And, I want to pass jwt token with header.

But, I pass it, get 401 error (Unauthorized).

In login actions.js :

```
export function login(username, password) {
return function(dispatch) {
  axios
  .post(`${API_URL}/auth/login`, { username, password })
  .then(res => {
    dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data, username));
    const token = res.data.token;
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token;
    history.push("/");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if (err.response.status === 401) {
      dispatch(loginFailure(err));
    }
  });
 };
}
```

And, In my post.js in server :

```
getToken = function(headers) {
  if (headers && headers.authorization) {
    var parted = headers.authorization.split(" ");
      if (parted.length === 2) {
       return parted[1];
      } else {
       return null;
      }
    } else {
     return null;
    }
 };
...
// Save Post
router.post("/", passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }), 
 function(
  req,
  res,
  next
  ) {
 var token = getToken(req.headers);
 if (token) {
   Post.create(req.body, function(err, post) {
     if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(post);
     });
   } else {
    return res.status(403).send({ success: false, msg: "Unauthorized." });
   }
});
```

How I do fix it?
 + Login is success

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First of all when you login and send username and password to backend then in response you get token_id. now try to token store in session_storage and redirect to your desire page. now you take token_id in your desire page and store one variable as like..

```
let user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data'));
const token = user.data.id;
```

now you have token and pass in the header and get data in response

```
const api = `your api here`
axios.get(api, { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`} })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
        this.setState({
            items: res.data,  /*set response data in items array*/
            isLoaded : true,
            redirectToReferrer: false
        })
```

**note :** you should set blank items array in initial setState as like

```
this.state={
            items:[],
            isLoaded: false,
            redirectToReferrer:false,
            token:''
        }
```

Comment: Actually, if I understand correctly, you shouldn't store the token in sessionStorage because hackers can then read and use the token.  There are alternatives out there, like saving in an httponly marked cookie, that may be safer.

Answer (score 12):

Include your token as authorization key as below.

```
axios.post(url,data, {
    headers: {
        'authorization': your_token,
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
.then(response => {
    // return  response;
})
.catch((error) => {
    //return  error;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**how-to-pass-header-jwt-token-with-axios-react ???**

---

This is example for create axios instance with **API Base URL** and **JWT_TOKEN**
globally and access it for different API calls

step 1 : create static instance for axios

```
static axiosInstance =  axios.create({
    baseURL: "BASE_API_URL",
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': "JWT_TOKEN",
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });
```

---

this is the second setep access axiosInstance already create and use it with **dynamic REST API** calls

step 2 : access static instance and bind **API_URL** to base URL

```
export const x = (data) => dispatch => {
    axiosInstance.post('API_URL',
        {
            PLAYLOAD
        })
        .then(function (response) {

        })
        .catch(function (error) {

        });
}
```

**API URL = BASE_API_URL + API_URL** and single **JWT_TOKEN** for all 
and this very clean , clear and working.

Answer (score 0):

Try res.header('x-auth', token).send()
'x-auth' can be anything. Above is used to set token in the headers